# Setting attachments to Read Only after upload to an item on a custom list

Tags: permissions, custom-list, attachments

I have a list where we add attachments to the list item.  I want the list item itself to be editable but I want to make the attachment read only.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable attachments.
Create a document library.
With a custom workflow (with sharepoint designer) you can create a folder in the document library titled with the ID of the item of your custom list.
You have to create a link beetwen the item and the document folder... you can do that in many way. A possibility is set a link column with the url of the folder. Use the same WF.
Or you can customize with infopath the custom list form and use a function to "calculate" the url.
Ok. The last step.
With another WF for the document library you can change the document permissions for every new document and set read only or what you want.

Comment: I like this idea, since the documents already existed in a document library and I was just adding them to the list for convenience.  Is it possible that I can link directly to the document instead of a folder?